# Comment enabled PDF

Tags: java, pdf, comments, pdf-generation

I have written a java program which enabled the shared review feature on a pdf. After making the pdf as Shared Review PDF it sends the pdf to a link folder in UNIX machine (link folder means shortcut path of a folder). After that an shell script, which runs differently via crontab makes the pdf as comment enabled and via the script that pdf is copied to some folder.

Now the question is whenever I am copying the file in the UNIX link folder (for copying the file to the link folder I am using **`FileUtils.copyInputStream()`** function.), a comment enabled script is executing and doing all comment enabled things in pdf(.sh script in UNIX which runs not from my program.) but during saving the file it prompts the file is readonly and exits without saving the file. But if I do the same thing (putting the file manually to the link folder in UNIX) manually it makes the pdf file as Comment enabled. This is my sample code which sends the file to a folder.

```
try{
                    String outFname="SR_"+fname;
                    srEnabledIs = new FileInputStream(pdfoutputPath+fname);

                    if(srEnabledIs!=null && !path.equals("")){
                        Date today = new Date();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss_a");
                        String timeStamp=format.format(today);
                        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(srEnabledIs, new File(path+outFname));
                        logtracker.writeDebugNormalLog("AnnotationMain","file copied to " + path);
                        try{
                            lrfile.renameTo(new File(pdfinputPath+"/pdf/"+fname.split("[.]")[0]+"_"+timeStamp+".pdf"));
                        }catch(Exception ex){
                            logtracker.writeDebugNormalLog("AnnotationMain", ex.getMessage());
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }                        
                    }else{
                        if(path.equals("")){
                            logtracker.writeDebugNormalLog("AnnotationMain", "File not copied as path not found.");
                        }
                        if(srEnabledIs==null){
                            logtracker.writeDebugNormalLog("AnnotationMain", "File not copied as InputStream is null.");
                        }
                        if(srEnabledIs==null && path.equals("")){
                            logtracker.writeDebugNormalLog("AnnotationMain", "File not copied as InputStream is null and path not found.");
                        }
                    }
                   }catch(IOException e){
                       logtracker.writeDebugNormalLog("AnnotationMain", e.getMessage());
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }finally{
                       if(srEnabledIs!=null){
                           srEnabledIs.close();
                       }
                   }
```

But the same program is running and executing successfully in other UNIX machine. I am really unable to understand the situation. Please help me out of this situation.

Comment: Am I putting my question in the wrong place? If that so I will stop asking question.

Comment: Nope, your question is in the right place.  There are few who have the experience to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @GilbertLeBlanc: At last I am feeling good after hearing from you. Will you please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc: Sir, Any update for this post?

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc: Still waiting...knock knock....

Comment: I don't have the experience to answer your question.

Comment: Hi @GilbertLeBlanc: After viewing your reputation, I felt like it was a nice joke. Laughed a lot. Thanks sir. Hoping someday I will get your favor.